# Media Recorder Chrome; Opentok audio not captured

Tags: google-chrome, audio, mediarecorder, opentok

looking for assistance from anyone who might have some insight into this. having a problem with the MediaRecorder API built into Chrome, specifically on macOS, a problem that does not appear at all on windows

i am needing to capture the desktop screen as well as the desktop audio, and currently i get the stream using:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
                video: {
                    cursor: 'always',
                    width: 1280,
                    height: 720,
                    frameRate: {
                        ideal: 12,
                        max: 15
                    },
                },
                audio: true
            })
```

this of course gives the prompt for the user to select a screen/application/tab
following that, i load that into a new MediaRecorder:

```
new MediaRecorder(screenCaptureStream, {mimeType: "video/webm"})
```

on windows this all works fine. as long as the "Share Audio" checkbox on the bottom left is marked, audio will be heard in the ending file.

on mac however, the only time a "Share Audio" option is allowed is when a chrome tab is selected. this is fine for something like a youtube tab playing music, it captures both video and audio without a problem.

however, on a tab running an opentok video session, no audio coming from the video session is captured. at first i thought it may have been ffmpeg incorrectly processing it, but simply playing back the raw webm file gives no audio. checking with mediaInfo the file does indeed come back with an audio stream at "48.0kHz, 32bits, 1 channel, Opus"

because this isnt a problem on windows, i imagine that the Opentok video session is somehow outputting in such a way that it it bypassing the chrome tab altogether, so that even is the user can hear the audio, the recorder doesnt capture it.

does anyone know how to allow chrome to record audio on the Application/Screen choices on macOS?

EDIT: upon more experimentation, ive discovered that the issue lies in tokbox streams themselves. 
setup: using a second pc, i hooked up my phone to a line-in port to use as the "mic" for the tokbox stream, and started up the session again. on that same page i have a youtube embedded iframe link to a random video, and on firefox, another video entirely.

selecting entire screen and making sure "Share Audio" is selected, i check that i can hear the audio being played from the phone on the other pc and its fine. the recording is going, and the checks for if there is an audio track pass. i swap to the next audio source by muting the 'phone' stream, and start playing the youtube embed. after a little bit, i stop it, and play the firefox video.

the results are that the embed and firefox audio got captured, but NONE of the tokbox audio got captured. (this was done on windows, so now i know its not a mac issue)

where is it being outputted?